# Testing with .in files without changing code

Tags: c++

I'm doing some programming problems from the previous year competition and in the problem text there is only one case, which is simple so I can just rewrite it when testing. 
Now, I also have a folder with a bunch of .in and .out files, in format '01.in, 01.out, 02.in, 02.out, etc'. 
Is there a way to somehow take one of those .in files and automatically use all the lines of it as input without making changes inside my program but rather doing it directly from the command line?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming linux:

`cat *.in | yourprogram`

On Windows you'd use `type` instead of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your program takes in and processes the agruments (argv[]) passed to it already. If this is the case, one way could be to write a simple wrapper program (in Python for example) which opens the required .in files, reads the lines in it and invokes your C++ program by passing the required lines as input to them.
Then you can execute this python program or make changes to it as required.